# Use of uniform boundedness theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces. Assume that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have a bounded linear operator $T_n:X\rightarrow Y$ and that $T_nx,\ n\in\mathbb{N}$ is convergent for each $x\in X$. Show that the operator $T:X\rightarrow Y$ given by

$$Tx:=\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}T_nx$$

is bounded.

Here is my attempt:

For $x\in X$ we have

$$||Tx||=||\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}T_nx||=\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}||T_nx||\leq\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}||T_n||\ ||x||$$

By the uniform boundedness theorem we have that there exists a $K$ such that $||T_n||\leq K$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ thus we have that $||Tx||\leq K||x||$ which implies $T$ is indeed bounded.

$\textbf{Remark:}$ I'm a little unsure whether I need some more arguments in the case of moving the limit outside of the norm? Furthermore, would the constant $K$ happen to be $\underset{n\in\mathbb{N}}{\sup}||T_n||$ in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(T_n(x))$ is convergent, hence bounded. That is why we can apply Uniform Boundeness Principle and conclude that $\sup_n \|T\|_n <\infty$ and that $\|T\| \leq \sup_n \|T\|_n $. The inequality you wrote is not correct.  We do not know that $\lim \|T_n\|$ exists.

Comment: But since $||T_n||\leq K$ by the uniform boundedness theorem, wouldn't we just have $||Tx||\leq\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}K||x||=K||x||$?

Comment: @James You wrote $\lim \|T_n\|$ (even before applying the theorem). How do you know that this limit exists?

Comment: I just wrote it since that was the definition of $T$. So, the issue is that I need to use the convergence of $T_nx$ to make use of the uniform boundedness theorem to then conclude that the limit exists and is finite thus $T$ is bounded? I don't need to do anything else? I think I'm just used to showing boundedness by direct calculation of $||Tx||$ etc.

Comment: But I do see your point in regards of the possibility of the limit not existing so that needs to be accounted for.

Comment: @James you cannot determine $\|T\|$ from the theorem . You can only say that it is finite. It is not true that $\|T_n\| \to \|T\|$.

Comment: I see what you're saying! But it is till correct that $K=\underset{n\in\mathbb{N}}{\sup}||T_n||$?

Comment: Yes, you can take $K$ to be this number and conclude that $\|T\| \leq K$.

Comment: But how can you conclude that $||T||\leq\underset{n}{\sup}||T_n||$?

Comment: Just change limit to supremum in the inequalities you have written (after first equality,).

Comment: Yes, since the limit is less than or equal to the supremum. I guess this is just to make sure I understand the procedure: Because $T_nx$ is convergent, which implies that it is bounded that allows for the use of the Uniform Boundedness Theorem. This yields that $\underset{n\in\mathbb{N}}{\sup}||T_n||<\infty$ and thus this shows the existence of $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}||T_n||$? I just wanna make sure I get the big picture.

Comment: @James You cannot say that $\lim \|T\|_n$ exists. You can only say that $\|T_n\|$ is bounded.

Comment: But you wrote "we do now know $\lim ||T_n||$ exists in your answer? I'm assuming you meant to say "not know"?